# What is the transparent film that covers water-soluble dishwasher tablets?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, plastics

These dishwasher tablets ([Finish Powerball Shine](http://www.finish.co.uk/shine-and-protect/)) seem to be covered in plastic!

[image: Film-covered dishwasher tablets]

But that can't possibly be true since there's no unwrapping, and they're completely soluble in water.

What is the film made of?

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/patents/US5972870

Comment: Keep in mind "plastic" encompasses many different chemical species. Many are soluble in water.

Comment: The MSDS sheets for the product you've linked to are available via email in the U.K. Here in the U.S., the manufacturer makes them available online. That said, there is not a U.S. product called Finish Powerball Shine, but [here is a link for Finish Powerball Quantum Max (Fresh Scent)](http://www.rbnainfo.com/productpro/ProductSearch.do?brandId=16&productLineId=1442&searchType=PL&template=1) where it is stated that "Ingredient polyvinyl alcohol" functions as a "Dissolvable Film." You might peruse the other U.S.-hosted Finish products to find a more suitable equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

It is made using Polyvinyl Alcohol (Mowiflex material).

Comment: Welcome to [chemistry.se]! Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some references about this material.